# Issue with CLLocation and double

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, double, cllocation

I have a longitude with -122.406417 and self.actualLongitude is a double member.

```
NSLog(@"original lon: %f",  [self.tempLocation coordinate].longitude);
NSLog(@"original lat: %f",  [self.tempLocation coordinate].latitude);
NSLog(@"original alt: %f",  [self.tempLocation altitude]);

self.actualLongitude = [self.tempLocation coordinate].longitude;
self.actualLatitude = [self.tempLocation coordinate].latitude;
self.actualLongitude = [self.tempLocation altitude];

NSLog(@"new lon: %f",  self.actualLongitude);
NSLog(@"new lat: %f",  self.actualLatitude);
NSLog(@"new alt: %f",  self.actualAltitude);
```

So why is self.actualLongitude 0.000000 ?

**2013-02-06 14:19:59.386 GeoCatching[4733:c07] original lon: -122.406417

2013-02-06 14:19:59.386 GeoCatching[4733:c07] original lat: 37.785834

2013-02-06 14:19:59.387 GeoCatching[4733:c07] original alt: 0.000000

2013-02-06 14:19:59.387 GeoCatching[4733:c07] new lon: 0.000000

2013-02-06 14:19:59.387 GeoCatching[4733:c07] new lat: 37.785834

2013-02-06 14:19:59.388 GeoCatching[4733:c07] new alt: 0.000000**

Note: Positive values are correct. I am using the simulator.

Comment: Are you sure that self.tempLocation is returning the same thing both times? Have you implemented your own setter or getter for self.actualLongitude?

Comment: What is the type of self.actualLongitude?

Comment: Yes, getter and setter are implemented for self.actualLongitude. Self.actualLongitude is a double. I do the same with latitude and altitude. Like i say, only the negative is not correct in my member.

Comment: Can you show the getters and setters you've written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line of your 3 assignments:

```
self.actualLongitude = [self.tempLocation altitude];
```

you overwrite the value of `self.actualLongitude` with the **altitude** (which happens
to be zero).

You probably mean

```
self.actualAltitude = [self.tempLocation altitude];
```